# regular expression for numbers with many spaces and special characters?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Hi I am new to the regular expression.

Can someone tell how to format a regular expression pattern for validating Numbers with many spaces and special characters? here the space position are not defined.

I have tried like this `^[0-9]{0,12}$` but I don't know how to place the spaces in-between ?

```
Ex:'2356 85 568#','5875 #2545','#2525','4567'
```

Comment: Please give a couple of examples for the string to parse and the expected result.

Comment: please add an example of a possible input, and your expected output

Comment: Have you already tried a regex tester? Like this: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html Examples would be useful.

Comment: Are the spaces and # include in the count of 12? Then see solutions bellow. Or do you want tu have upto 12 numbers with maybe 345 Whitespaces in between?

Comment: No ,spaces and # shouldn't include in the count of 12 and it should allow the # only once @dognose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow any number of spaces, dashes and #-signs between up to 12 numbers, use this:

```
^[ #-]*([0-9][ #-]*){0,12}$
```

- initially 0 or more specials
- then 0-12 groups of

  - one digit
  - followed by 0 or more specials

Comment: Thanks sir,If suppose i wants to limit occurrence of the spaces and dashes and # then how should i modify the above one? @Hans Kesting

Comment: @user1863261 - I don't think it's possible to limit both the digits and the specials, other than like this: `^[ #-]*([0-9][ #-]{0,2}){0,12}$`. You will need another test to check for "max 4 specials in total".

Answer (score 1):

If you want at most twelve digits, and an unlimited amount of whitespace and hash signs, you can do this:

```
^[\s#]*([0-9][\s#]*){0,12}$
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow "spaces and special characters" to include any non-digit characters, use:

```
^\D*(\d\D*){0,12}$
```

To explain:

- `^\D*` matches any non-digit characters at the start of the string
- `(\d\D*)` matches a single digit followed by any non-digits
- `{0,12}` allow the previous group to occur up to 12 times